# Send API POST request with all data in url from within MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm contacting external API that excepts only values posted via url:

```
https://api.solo.com.hr/racun?token:aisudfhlashf&tip_usluge:....
```

I have constructed the string to append to url:

```
PrepareData(Model model)
{
    string s = "?";
    s += "token:" + lApp.GetSoloApiToken() + "&";
    s += "tip_usluge:" + "1" + "&";
    s += "prikazi_porez:" + "1" + "&";
    ...
    return(s);
}
```

I can't find method that would except only url, or data in string format. I have tried WebClient() and HttpClient()

```
string data = PrepareData(model);
var response = client.UploadValues("https://api.solo.com.hr/racun" + data); // of course doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `null` as content parameter to `HttpClient.PostAsync(...)` will send POST request with empty body

```
HttpClient client;
...
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.solo.com.hr/racun" + data, null);
```